# Send imageview to WCF from Android

Tags: android, wcf, post, imageview

I converted the imageview to bitmap and later to Base64 string, after that i am sending it via post to the server.
I am receiving the stream in my WCF but the file that is saved is corrupted, the image file is unable to see.

Android code:

```
   private void upload() {
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) perfilimg.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = drawable.getBitmap();

    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
    byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
    // Upload image to server
    new uploadToServer().execute();
}
    public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Perfil.this);
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.setMessage("Uploading image...");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64", ba1));
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://dotstudioservices.com/elswitchService/Service1.svc/perfilimagen");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e("Pruebas", result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        return "Success";

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.hide();
        pd.dismiss();
    }
```

WCF Code:

```
        public Estatus FileUpload(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[50000];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, 50000);

    string   filePath = "D:\\Hosting\\9692238\\html\\promosbc\\imagenesElSwitch\\profile.jpg";

        FileStream f = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        f.Close();
        stream.Close();
        return new Estatus { estatus = "success" };
    }
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Well you are not doing a file upload. What you do is sending a normal key value text pair. So i even wonder that something is saved to file. Have a look in it with wordpad to see what is saved.

Comment: I have something like this: base64=%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2F2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQE....

Comment: Ok. Indeed the key=value pair as i already told you. Remove the base64= from it and you have the base64 encoded image. Now you can decode it. But there are unallowed chars in that string like %2F. That looks like an url encoded character. Did you url encode the string before posting? Or you could url decode this string before you decode it base64.

Comment: In the code i have: httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); I supposed that i should send the base64 encode without the nameValuePairs...

Comment: well i guess that i need to send a list... i can't send only a string

Comment: Where are you talking about?

Comment: how can i avoid those unallowed chars?

Comment: Do not use UrlEncodedFormEntity i would say. Isn't there a FormUntity? Otherwise -as said before- url decode at receiver side. But better you upload it as file. Use FileBody. You dont need to base64 encode it then.

Comment: ok i already got this kind of file: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/ 
now...  how i can decode it?

Comment: Decode it with a base64 decoder. You did not tell what IDE you use for server side coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help everyone i will post my answer, i changed the Android code like this:

```
private void upload() {
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) perfilimg.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmapOrg = drawable.getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
new uploadToServer().execute();
}

public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Perfil.this);
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd.setMessage("Uploading image...");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://dotstudioservices.com/elswitchService/Service1.svc/perfilimagen");
        httppost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(ba));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Log.e("Pruebas", result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
    return "Success";

}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    pd.hide();
    pd.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing a Base64 decode on the receiving end before writing to the file.

Comment: i dont know how to do that from the Stream

Comment: Then do it after that from the file with its base64 contents.